# Check Empty Input doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I'm trying to check if the input is empty with jQuery and the code doesn't work.

That's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="demo.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name">
            <input type="submit" id="btnConnect">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
$('#btnConnect').click(function()
{
    if($('#name').val() == '')
    {
        alert('Input is empty!');
    }
});
```

Comment: check for undefined

Comment: When I run your code, I get an alert "Input is empty" without a filled out input.

Comment: wrap the code in $(document).ready(function(){}); it shoud work as it is

Comment: It works with $(document). But I don't understand why it doesn't work with my code, because I've seen the same code on another script and it works well. Thanks!

Comment: @Geeky is probably right. I assume the JS portion you pasted is from `demo.js`, which is loaded before the body of the page is parsed. This means that the event listener attempts to attach to `#btnConnect` when that element hasn't been parsed yet - so it attaches to nothing instead. You can either use the `$(document).ready()` function to postpone the script execution until the DOM is parsed, or you can put the script at the end of your body so the DOM is parsed anyway before the script is executed.

Comment: Load your `<script>`s at the end, before the closing body `</body>`, if you don't want to use $(document).ready().

Comment: And, what can I do if i have multiple inputs to check? Because as can I see, document is global. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new on jQuery.

Comment: It's ok guys, I loaded my script before closing body and it works well. Thank you for your support!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready ...Read about document.ready ,you should make sure of wrapping your jQuery code within document.ready because it executes when whole html page gets rendered,if without this ,your js code gets executed and their may be a chance of not finding your input element

Comment: but should read about document.ready and window.onload,they play very important role in js code

Comment: If my answer helps, please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has two easy solutions.
Basically, you call your script before the rest of the page loads. Your script tries to attach to `#btnConnect`, which doesn't exist yet.

**1).**  Use `document.ready` or   `window.onload`. The script will only execute after the whole page loads, so it should work as you meant it to.

**2).**  Place the `JS` files at the bottom of the document, right before the closing `body` tag. Most programmers chose to put the `scripts` at the bottom of the page, because if you have large scripts, the user sees a blank page untill they load.
It works quite well, because most of the time JS is not required until the user begins interacting with the site. It also enables progressive rendering.

For more good JS practices, check out:

> [JSTheRightWay.org](http://jstherightway.org/)

Hope this helps!